# Thrust conversion loss data warnings

Tags: cuda, thrust

I was trying to use thrust to perform a reduction on some data but at compile time I get a lot of warnings regarding possible conversion loss of data

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/cuda_launch_config.h(338) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t thrust::system::cuda::detail::block_size_with_maximum_potential_occupancy<thrust::system::cuda::detail::cuda_launch_config_detail::util::zero_function<T>>(const thrust::system::cuda::detail::function_attributes_t &,const thrust::system::cuda::detail::device_properties_t &,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=size_t,
1>              UnaryFunction=thrust::system::cuda::detail::cuda_launch_config_detail::util::zero_function<size_t>
1>          ]
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/cuda_launch_config.h(147): warning C4267: 'return' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>          C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/cuda_launch_config.h(159) : see reference to function template instantiation 'L thrust::system::cuda::detail::cuda_launch_config_detail::util::divide_ri<L,R>(const L,const R)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              L=int,
1>              R=size_t
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/cuda_launch_config.h(272) : see reference to function template instantiation 'L thrust::system::cuda::detail::cuda_launch_config_detail::util::round_i<L,size_t>(const L,const R)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              L=int,
1>              R=size_t
1>          ]
```

I know those are warnings but they are really annoying, is there any way to turn off these?

Comment: So, have you got any way to avoid these warnings without ignoring them? I find it is hard because thrust is a template library, it is even hard to find what was going wrong, not to say modify the code of thrust.

Comment: Has anyone figured out these warnings? Can't be a good thing.

I can't see anyplace in my Thrust code where I'm using `int` inappropriately and I see many/most of these warnings are internal to Thrust -- on the startup code and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two years later, and the problem(s) still exist. I have figured out what's going on here, and have a solution.

First, to restate the problem. If you create a brand new CUDA project (I'm using CUDA 7.5 and Visual Studio 2013) and put in simply this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<int> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Then switch the project to 64-bit (change the config to x64, which changes the compiler to 64 code generation), you get several warnings from within Thrust that complain about conversion loss from `size_t` to `int`. These warnings all are coming (at least today) from the Thrust `execution_policy.hpp` include file.

In that file there are several cases where the type `size_type` is defined as `int`, then later used as an equivalent or return value for `size_t` data. That explains the warnings. In MSVC 64-bit-land a `size_t` is 2x the size of an `int`.

As a test, I've changed the several instances of:

```
typedef int size_type;
```

in `execution_policy.hpp` to:

```
typedef size_t size_type;
```

and all the warnings go away.

I'm going now over to the Thrust github project and suggest just such a change.

Hope this helps somebody, it's been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `#pragma warning (disable : 4267)` I'd assume. However, if you don't have a convincing reason not to do so, I'd fix the code instead.

`size_t` and `int` are not the same thing. What might work for you now could end up biting you in places you don't want to be bitten at some point. See ["Why size_t matters"](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/Why-size-t-matters) for example.